# Eclipse/CDT editor not picking up project-defined symbols in coloring ifdef'ed out sections

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

The problem I'm seeing is that under preferences, C/C++ Defined symbols for different Configurations/targets aren't showing up in the code coloring.

When I change the active build configuration in the project menu, I would expect the editor & code coloring to pick up the symbols from the project settings, but it only seems to be picking up the symbols for one of the targets.

Is there any way to have the code coloring for ifdef'ed code follow the active build configuration?

Answer (score 21):

I solved this problem on my system by setting 'Window->Preferences->C/C++->Indexer->Use active build configuration'

Comment: Thanks.  Never would have found that.  I had to refresh something to get this to take, but I'm not sure what. That is, it didn't "take" right away, and I tried rebuilding the index and re-applying the symbols, but this didn't seem to work.  20 minutes later I noticed it was working.  I'm not sure what happened.  Might want to restart eclipse, refresh buffers, etc.

Comment: I know it's against SO's guidelines to say thanks, but seriously, thank you. Been battling with this for ages.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I wanted and never would have found it!  Need to right click project->Index->Rebuild and is all good.

Answer (score 5):

In response to phord's comment. After changing the indexer setting to "Use Active Configuration" you need to change the active conf of the project to something else and then back. Then it picks up the changes.

Answer (score 2):

just a small addition to the symbols option:
give it value 1

what worked for me is this:

- copy the define name to clipboard(lets say we have: #ifdef DBG_TYP_1)
- select the project in project explorer
- go to - Project->Properties->C/C++ General->Path and Symbols
- in the "# Symbols" tab
- **add symbol** DBG_TYP_1 **with value 1**

thanks for the tips !

Comment: My original project didn't have the symbols tab and I just couldn't get it work any other way. I created a new project and this time selected GCC presets which gave me the symbols tab. This mechanism worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing around with your project's Discovery Options.  (Right-click on the project, choose Properties, go under C/C++ Build, and choose Discovery Options.)

You may need to rebuild your project after changing its build configuration in order for Eclipse to rerun its discovery, or you may need to change the discovery options for each configuration to cause them to generate different results.  (Sorry, this isn't an area of the CDT that I've played much with.)

Comment: Both 'automate discovery of paths and symbols' and 'Report path detection problems' are selected, and the Discovery profiles scope is set to 'Per Language'. These were the default settings.

Rebuilding after changing the active build doesn't seem to make any difference in the code coloring for the ifdef'ed out sections.