# Eclipse CDT. "Syntax error" when using Symbols

Tags: c, eclipse, syntax-error, eclipse-cdt

I am developing two embedded projects quite similar (they share most of the code) for the same target. To do so, I created two builds: Build A and Build B. Each build has some minor differences defined in the Symbols: "DEVICE_TYPE=" to include or exclude source code depending on the project. So that I can do the following,

```
#if (DEVICE_TYPE == A)
[Code for build A]
#endif

#if (DEVICE_TYPE == B)
[Code for build B]
#endif
```

My problem here is that the Eclipse's Syntax is always throwing errors because, apparently it always thinks that DEVICE_TYPE is equal to B. Both builds compile without any problem, though.

UPDATE:

The symbols are defined in Project_Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings->Compiler->Preprocessor->Define Syms (-D) as follows:

In case of Build A

```
DEVICE_TYPE=A
A=0
B=1
```

In case of Build B

```
DEVICE_TYPE=B
A=0
B=1
```

Here the problem is that for Eclipse, the DEVICE_TYPE is always B, no matter which Build is selected. That implies that all code within `#if (DEVICE_TYPE==A)` is grey.

Comment: You need to be more specific. How are `A`, `B` and `DEVICE_TYPE` defined? Also, code excluded due to `#if` is grayed out, is that the case?

Comment: I hope this new update solves your doubts.

Comment: May be a dumb guess: have you tried defining A & B prior to DEVICE_TYPE ?

Comment: check with `#if (DEVICE_TYPE=='A')` and `#if (DEVICE_TYPE == 'B')`

Comment: Geoffroy: Yep, I already tried.
SparKot: A and B are actually numbers, 0 and 1 respectively. I just used A and B as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the Eclipse setting for "use active build settings" mentioned in this answer:
[use active build settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951855/eclipse-cdt-editor-not-picking-up-project-defined-symbols-in-coloring-ifdefed-o?rq=1) ?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! That solved my problem! I love stack overflow!